# Polymer Routing with page.js do not add hashbang to URLs when links are opened in new tab

Tags: javascript, polymer, polymer-1.0, page.js

I am using polymer starter kit which uses `page.js` for routing. The `hashbang` `page` option is set to `true` in `routing.html`

```
// add #! before urls
page({
  hashbang: true
});
```

when links such as `<a href="/products/productname"></a>` are clicked, the `#!` is added and the resulting url looks like this: `http://localhost:3000/#!/products/productname` but when the links are opened in a new browser tab, they look like this `http://localhost:3000/products/productname`. How can I have the `#!` added when links are opened in new tab?

Comment: There is already an issue for that ... https://github.com/visionmedia/page.js/issues/276

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to write

```
<a href="#!/products/productname"
```

in every your href